# Fire rewrite rule on class constraint

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a `maybeShow` function which is `show` but without a `Show` class constraint. Here's my attempt:

```
{-# INLINE [1] maybeShow #-}
maybeShow :: a -> Maybe String
maybeShow _ = Nothing

canShow :: Show a => a -> Maybe String
canShow = Just . show

data CantShow = CantShow

main = do
  print (maybeShow (42 :: Int))
  print (maybeShow CantShow)

{-# RULES
"maybeShow" forall (x :: (Show a => a)). maybeShow x = canShow x
#-}
```

But in this code, the rewrite rule never seems to fire.

I know this will sometimes return `Nothing` for showable types. For example, I entirely expect uses of `maybeShow` in non-inlined functions which are not specialised to a particular type to return `Nothing`. But as I'm using `maybeShow` as something to add to the output of `error`, it doesn't really matter if it doesn't always work.

But I'd like it to sometimes work (for example, when it's been inlined into the calling function) rather than never as seems to be currently the case.

Any ideas on how to get the rewrite rule to fire? This on [wiki.haskell.org](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Using_rules#Rules_and_sections) suggests it can be done, but the advice dates back to GHC 6.6 so I'm not sure it's still valid.

Comment: I don't think you can make a rule fire conditionally to the existence of an instance, because as the page you linked to indicates, rules apply after dictionaries are expanded, and then become simple syntactic checks.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Show variables for debugging purposes (ie in 'error' calls) without requiring a show constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are still unclear to me, but I can't think of other solutions than the following two, e.g., to debug a library of polymorphic functions by tracing trace values of parametric types, but adding a `Show` constraint would break code downstream.

---

Use rewrite rules on monomorphic types. I assume that for debugging purposes, you need only a few types. However this may be rather unreliable, and you might need to specialise/inline functions explicitly.

---

Perhaps you can get by with another type class with a blanket overlappable instance.

```
class MaybeShow a where
  maybeShow :: a -> Maybe String

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} MaybeShow a where
  maybeShow _ = Nothing
```

You then specialize it selectively to the few types you are using to debug.

```
instance MaybeShow Int where
  maybeShow n = Just (show n)
```

However you still need to add a `MaybeShow` constraint to every function that uses it.

Here you can often use `PartialTypeSignatures` to write more concise toplevel signatures

```
myFun :: _ => a -> w a
constrainedFun :: (_, RealConstraint a) => a -> b a
```

This method however has the advantage of having much more predictable behavior.